# Dashboard supporting d3

Tags: highcharts, business-intelligence, dashboard, d3.js

I'm interested in a web-based dashboard with some sort of d3.js library widget or more general javascript support. I've been trying geckoboard's HighCharts widget but I'm not especially happy with the results (a little limited for what I'm looking for). Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think [jslate](http://jslate.com) is just that: highcharts + d3.

Comment: there's not much documentation for jslate...the site is pretty bare.  It does look interesting but I'd like to see more examples of its uses.

Comment: No docs. No contact. Nothing!

Answer (score 1):

I personally am finding D3 to be very powerful.  There are a number of different solutions that allow the development of interactive dashboards.  The only problem I've found is that the library is still rather new and has limited user documentation that helps clearly show examples of how to use the majority of what's specified in its API.  I typically find the answers to my questions by scouring through the complex examples that are out there.  However, once you start to learn it you realize just how impressive it really is.

I'm working on building my own dashboards using charts and have been able to build the following examples...

- [Multiple Pie Charts Mixed In With Common HTML Layout Constructs](http://bl.ocks.org/2212156)
- [Multiple Vertical Bar Charts Mixed In With Common HTML Layout Constructs](http://bl.ocks.org/2164562)

Each is the beginning of an attempt to get to more complex dashboards that will mix different types of charts and visualizations.

I hope this helps.

Frank

Comment: I find the documentation very thorough.  There is a lot in the wiki `https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference` and the google group is very active `http://groups.google.com/group/d3-js`.